# Convert String to Double - precision lost

Tags: c++, string, double, typeconverter

I am reading from a file that contains text and numbers to a string array. When I convert the string to a double for calculations I lose precision. The value I'm returning should be equal to 284262.5862225, but in main I only get a value of 284262. No digits after the decimal seem to get returned. My code is below.

```
ifstream inFile("test.txt");
string line;
int row, col;
double value;
string head[6][2]={};
row=0;

if (!inFile.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error opening xyz file. . .";

}
else
{
    while(row<6)
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
        stringstream ss (line);
        col=0;
        while (ss>>head[row][col])
        {
            col++;
        }
        row++;

    }
    inFile.close();
}

stringstream convert (head[2][1]);
convert>>value;
return value;
```

Sample of File:

nrows 270
ncols 730
xll   284262.586255
yll   792350

Comment: maybe the `stringstream` treats . as delimiter?

Comment: Do you have a sample of your file?

Comment: Sample of the file is here:

Comment: ncols         270
nrows         730
xllcorner     284262.586255
yllcorner     792350
cellsize      1
NODATA_value  -9999

Comment: Apologies, i'm not used to this text formatting. I added a sample of the file below the code block

Comment: @TheOne I don't think stringstream treats . as a delimiter because I can update the file to have a shorter double (e.g. 234.453) and it works just fine. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me. The problem is probably that you are printing value with cout, and it is only printing the first 6 significant numbers (here is the part before the dot). If you include the library

```
#include <iomanip>
```

and you increase the precision of the output, it should work.

```
cout << setprecision (13) << value << endl;
```